# Which is better: for valid buffer length?

Tags: c, malloc, buffers

This is a basic question. But, I think understanding this would be helpful to play with buffers in 'C'. Thanks.

### Scenario

Just a sample snippet

```
char *test_buff = (char *) malloc(512); //allocate 512 bytes in heap memory.
bzero(test_buff, 512); //Reset buffer instead of Junk/garbage.
/* random code here to fill-in the buffer called "test_buff"...*/
...
/* Send data to another host/system [this doesn't matter though]
 * using buffer "test_buff".
 */
 sendto(sock_descriptor, test_buff /*buffer to send data*/, sizeof(*test_buff) ,...,...);  // option-1
/* OR */
 sendto(sock_descriptor, test_buff /*buffer to send data*/, 512 /* actual malloced size*/ ,...,...); // option-2
```

### Question

1. Which one of the two is better [between option-1/option-2] way of using buffer? I hope option-1 makes sense, as it has length/size of valid data bytes of send buffer or "test_buff" in this case.

Thanks for your time and input.

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof(*test_buff)` is computed at compile time and will evaluate to the size of a single element of `test_buff`. As `test_buff` is a buffer of `char`'s, that element size is guaranteed to be 1.
If I have to choose between the two options that you give, then only option 2 has useful behaviour.

On the other hand, if there comes a time that you need to change the size of your buffer, then you have to make that change in 3 (or 4 or 5) places and you have to look out for the places where the number 512 is used with a different meaning. For this reason, my preferred way of writing the code is like this:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 512
char *test_buff = (char *) malloc(BUFFER_SIZE); //allocate 512 bytes in heap memory.
bzero(test_buff, BUFFER_SIZE); //Reset buffer instead of Junk/garbage.
/* random code here to fill-in the buffer called "test_buff"...*/
...
/* Send data to another host/system [this doesn't matter though]
 * using buffer "test_buff".
 */
 sendto(sock_descriptor, test_buff /*buffer to send data*/, BUFFER_SIZE /* actual malloced size*/ ,...,...); // option-2a
```

If you want to send only the used portion of the buffer, you either need to keep explicitly track of that, or if your buffer only holds a single string, you can use `strlen(test_buff)+1` (+1 to ensure the terminating `'\0'` is also transmitted).

Answer (score 3):

In as much as `sizeof(*test_buff)` will be `sizeof(char)`, i.e. `1`, I'd go with the `512`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Keith. Just to clarify, I thought sizeof(*test_buff) should point to number of bytes till null termination is reached. I guess, that happens if I had  used strlen(test_buff), is it?

Comment: Yes, assuming that the buffer contains a text string with a null terminator, you could use `strlen(test_buff) + 1`. I really recommend the `1` so that you send the null as well, although if you precede the send with a length field that is not mandatory.

Comment: In case it isn't obvious, strlen(test_buff) is very unlikely to return 512.  Whoever is receiving the message will need to know what to expect, so someone needs to decide whether you're sending a variable length string or a fixed length buffer.